# Two tabs displaying same tab-content with unique ID values in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-4, nav

I'm using Python Flask, Jinja 2 and Boostrap 4 for developing a simple web tool but I'm stuck on a weird issue that I believe must be a linkage error between the "nav-item" and a "tabpanel" but for the life of me I can't seem to find the problem. Below is the code I'm using for the tabs in HTML.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#m-tab" role="tab">M</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#g-tab" role="tab">G</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href= "#p-tab" role="tab">P</a></li>
  </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="m-tab" role"tabpanel">
    ....... <!-- Content -->
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="g-tab" role="tabpanel">
    ....... <!-- Content -->
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="p-tab" role="tabpanel">
    ....... <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The first two tabs, `m-tab and g-tab`, work perfectly, but when I select the `p-tab` the content displayed does not change from the `g-tab tabpanel`. It seems that both the second and third tab are displaying the same content as the url updates to show which tab is active and that part correctly reflects the selection I make.

I have to be missing something simple but I need a second pair of eyes!
Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Works fine for me: https://www.bootply.com/YREPSCCAu6

Comment: The furthest I can get is for the third tab to appear only once. Switching off to a new tab then back again reverts to the second tab's content when the third tab is selected. Could this be something to do with the `active` keyword? I believe I'm using it correctly above. @Pete

Comment: Can't tell you what to do without a [MCVE] demonstrating your problem.  As your code works as it is provided, I cannot help you